# Make an API call even if internet is not available

Tags: ios, swift4

So I'm working on an IoT app, where I need to configure the hardware by connecting to its WiFi. If I use AFNetworking or URLSession to make the call, they fail with this error message.

`"The Internet connection appears to be offline."`

I need a way to make the API call to the local Wifi of the hardware by overriding the Reachability check. I'm sure there must be a way to do so, but I can't seem to come across something like that.

Answer (score 0):

[Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) tells you if a certain host is reachable via Wifi. `reachability.connection == .wifi` test should be enough for that.

However, to know the reachability via that utility, you must know your host's IP *within the wifi network*, not internet.

What are all IP addresses that your host exposes? They will each belong to a network - internet, wifi, LAN and such.

What you probably need is the correct network utility to tell you that, for example, [arp](http://osxdaily.com/2016/11/03/view-lan-device-ip-address-arp/).